Ubuntu 24.04 Battery Indicator Problems, value doesn't change
All, I just installed a fresh copy of 24.04 on an hp elitebook laptop.
My battery indicator reads ~40% charged but that value will not change.
I continued to use the laptop like normal and as expected it eventually died.  If I plug the  laptop in to charge, the laptop is charging, but the battery reader indicates 0% charged.

Nevermind, issue was due to a bad battery.  I noticed one of the indicator lights was blinking amber.  Swapped in a new battery and laptop is charging correctly and ubuntu is reporting the correct charge.
